# Azure Pipelines build error nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Error NU5012: Unable to find... Make sure the project has been built

Tags: .net, azure, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I have been wrestling with Azure pipelines to build some nuget packages into an artifact feed but I cannot get past the "Nuget Pack" job I have set up for the pipeline. It is failing when trying to find the NCrunch.Framework.dll.  The other .ddl's were packaged fine based on the job logs but something about NCrunch and azure is not agreeing and I cannot find any resources about this. I have opened the project and built it, and the "vs build" job previous to the pack job runs successfully.  A few other lines I am not sure if relevant to this issue:

```
WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:

Add a dependency group for .NETFramework4.8 to the nuspec

Successfully created package 'D:\a\1\a\ourbox.nupkg'.
Attempting to pack file: D:\a\1\s\repo\packages\NCrunch.Framework.3.3.0.6\NCrunch.Framework.csproj
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.8.1\x64\nuget.exe pack D:\a\1\s\repo\packages\NCrunch.Framework.3.3.0.6\NCrunch.Framework.csproj -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory D:\a\1\a -Properties Configuration=release;Platform=AnyCpu;version=1.0; -Verbosity Detailed
Error NU5012: Unable to find 'D:\a\1\s\repo\packages\ClientBinaries\Release\NCrunch.Framework.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the latest nuget version.

This error is because of solution builds with "Platform=Any CPU", but a project builds with "**Platform=AnyCPU**".

You can try with Removing the space in your platform value and it should work.

Comment: cannot see anywhere in the question "Platform=Any CPU", how could you find it?

Comment: @RollendXavier It would be like this-
```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
```